# convert geoJson data to sql server spatial data type (GIS)

Tags: c#, json, gis, spatial, geojson

I've downloaded from openstreetmaps administrative borders (city, region, country, etc...) in geoJson format.

I'm trying to store the json data related to the polygons in my ms sql server using spatial data. Since I've never parsed such a complex json file I've got difficulties in manually creating a c# object to store the parsed data.

I'm using newtonsoftJson.json, to read the geoJson file and create an object.
Then I use reflection to get the properties related to the object. This is quite a tedious task because in some cases the objects are nested in more than 4 levels in the geojson file. Since I've got to store the polygons for all the cities in the world, I clearly need a faster and accurate way of doing it.

1. What could be the best method of achieving my goal?
2. I guess json schemas could be of great help, but how?
3. Is there a standard geoJson schema, in the sense that if I use the schema for openstreetmaps and an other GIS framework (google maps), will it be compatible?

Answer (score 14):

This can be done in pure SQL in SqlServer 2016, as @javan-MSFT has answered in 2015. Doing this in SQL means there are no runtime dependencies, you can easily upload static data records directly in SSMS, but I tell you what it's not as easy as it perhaps should be, the links in MSDN blogs are a basic start but wont help you  in a hurry:

- [Parsing GeoJSON format in Sql Server 2016](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/Parsing-GeoJSON-format-in-Sql-Server-2016/ba-p/384459?advanced=false&collapse_discussion=true&q=geojson&search_type=thread)
- [Loading GeoJSON data into SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/Loading-GeoJSON-data-into-SQL-Server/ba-p/384601?advanced=false&collapse_discussion=true&q=geojson&search_type=thread)

Without posting a snippet of your dataset, I can't tailor a query that will work 100% but I can show you using a snippet of data that I sourced from https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json This is a good low res GeoJSON file, hi res files follow the same structure just have a lot more points.

```
declare @worldGeoJson nvarchar(max) = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"AFG","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,35.650072],[62.230651,35.270664],[62.984662,35.404041],[63.193538,35.857166],[63.982896,36.007957],[64.546479,36.312073],[64.746105,37.111818],[65.588948,37.305217],[65.745631,37.661164],[66.217385,37.39379],[66.518607,37.362784],[67.075782,37.356144],[67.83,37.144994],[68.135562,37.023115],[68.859446,37.344336],[69.196273,37.151144],[69.518785,37.608997],[70.116578,37.588223],[70.270574,37.735165],[70.376304,38.138396],[70.806821,38.486282],[71.348131,38.258905],[71.239404,37.953265],[71.541918,37.905774],[71.448693,37.065645],[71.844638,36.738171],[72.193041,36.948288],[72.63689,37.047558],[73.260056,37.495257],[73.948696,37.421566],[74.980002,37.41999],[75.158028,37.133031],[74.575893,37.020841],[74.067552,36.836176],[72.920025,36.720007],[71.846292,36.509942],[71.262348,36.074388],[71.498768,35.650563],[71.613076,35.153203],[71.115019,34.733126],[71.156773,34.348911],[70.881803,33.988856],[69.930543,34.02012],[70.323594,33.358533],[69.687147,33.105499],[69.262522,32.501944],[69.317764,31.901412],[68.926677,31.620189],[68.556932,31.71331],[67.792689,31.58293],[67.683394,31.303154],[66.938891,31.304911],[66.381458,30.738899],[66.346473,29.887943],[65.046862,29.472181],[64.350419,29.560031],[64.148002,29.340819],[63.550261,29.468331],[62.549857,29.318572],[60.874248,29.829239],[61.781222,30.73585],[61.699314,31.379506],[60.941945,31.548075],[60.863655,32.18292],[60.536078,32.981269],[60.9637,33.528832],[60.52843,33.676446],[60.803193,34.404102],[61.210817,35.650072]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"ARE","properties":{"name":"United Arab Emirates"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[51.579519,24.245497],[51.757441,24.294073],[51.794389,24.019826],[52.577081,24.177439],[53.404007,24.151317],[54.008001,24.121758],[54.693024,24.797892],[55.439025,25.439145],[56.070821,26.055464],[56.261042,25.714606],[56.396847,24.924732],[55.886233,24.920831],[55.804119,24.269604],[55.981214,24.130543],[55.528632,23.933604],[55.525841,23.524869],[55.234489,23.110993],[55.208341,22.70833],[55.006803,22.496948],[52.000733,23.001154],[51.617708,24.014219],[51.579519,24.245497]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"AUS","properties":{"name":"Australia"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[145.397978,-40.792549],[146.364121,-41.137695],[146.908584,-41.000546],[147.689259,-40.808258],[148.289068,-40.875438],[148.359865,-42.062445],[148.017301,-42.407024],[147.914052,-43.211522],[147.564564,-42.937689],[146.870343,-43.634597],[146.663327,-43.580854],[146.048378,-43.549745],[145.43193,-42.693776],[145.29509,-42.03361],[144.718071,-41.162552],[144.743755,-40.703975],[145.397978,-40.792549]]],[[[143.561811,-13.763656],[143.922099,-14.548311],[144.563714,-14.171176],[144.894908,-14.594458],[145.374724,-14.984976],[145.271991,-15.428205],[145.48526,-16.285672],[145.637033,-16.784918],[145.888904,-16.906926],[146.160309,-17.761655],[146.063674,-18.280073],[146.387478,-18.958274],[147.471082,-19.480723],[148.177602,-19.955939],[148.848414,-20.39121],[148.717465,-20.633469],[149.28942,-21.260511],[149.678337,-22.342512],[150.077382,-22.122784],[150.482939,-22.556142],[150.727265,-22.402405],[150.899554,-23.462237],[151.609175,-24.076256],[152.07354,-24.457887],[152.855197,-25.267501],[153.136162,-26.071173],[153.161949,-26.641319],[153.092909,-27.2603],[153.569469,-28.110067],[153.512108,-28.995077],[153.339095,-29.458202],[153.069241,-30.35024],[153.089602,-30.923642],[152.891578,-31.640446],[152.450002,-32.550003],[151.709117,-33.041342],[151.343972,-33.816023],[151.010555,-34.31036],[150.714139,-35.17346],[150.32822,-35.671879],[150.075212,-36.420206],[149.946124,-37.109052],[149.997284,-37.425261],[149.423882,-37.772681],[148.304622,-37.809061],[147.381733,-38.219217],[146.922123,-38.606532],[146.317922,-39.035757],[145.489652,-38.593768],[144.876976,-38.417448],[145.032212,-37.896188],[144.485682,-38.085324],[143.609974,-38.809465],[142.745427,-38.538268],[142.17833,-38.380034],[141.606582,-38.308514],[140.638579,-38.019333],[139.992158,-37.402936],[139.806588,-36.643603],[139.574148,-36.138362],[139.082808,-35.732754],[138.120748,-35.612296],[138.449462,-35.127261],[138.207564,-34.384723],[137.71917,-35.076825],[136.829406,-35.260535],[137.352371,-34.707339],[137.503886,-34.130268],[137.890116,-33.640479],[137.810328,-32.900007],[136.996837,-33.752771],[136.372069,-34.094766],[135.989043,-34.890118],[135.208213,-34.47867],[135.239218,-33.947953],[134.613417,-33.222778],[134.085904,-32.848072],[134.273903,-32.617234],[132.990777,-32.011224],[132.288081,-31.982647],[131.326331,-31.495803],[129.535794,-31.590423],[128.240938,-31.948489],[127.102867,-32.282267],[126.148714,-32.215966],[125.088623,-32.728751],[124.221648,-32.959487],[124.028947,-33.483847],[123.659667,-33.890179],[122.811036,-33.914467],[122.183064,-34.003402],[121.299191,-33.821036],[120.580268,-33.930177],[119.893695,-33.976065],[119.298899,-34.509366],[119.007341,-34.464149],[118.505718,-34.746819],[118.024972,-35.064733],[117.295507,-35.025459],[116.625109,-35.025097],[115.564347,-34.386428],[115.026809,-34.196517],[115.048616,-33.623425],[115.545123,-33.487258],[115.714674,-33.259572],[115.679379,-32.900369],[115.801645,-32.205062],[115.689611,-31.612437],[115.160909,-30.601594],[114.997043,-30.030725],[115.040038,-29.461095],[114.641974,-28.810231],[114.616498,-28.516399],[114.173579,-28.118077],[114.048884,-27.334765],[113.477498,-26.543134],[113.338953,-26.116545],[113.778358,-26.549025],[113.440962,-25.621278],[113.936901,-25.911235],[114.232852,-26.298446],[114.216161,-25.786281],[113.721255,-24.998939],[113.625344,-24.683971],[113.393523,-24.384764],[113.502044,-23.80635],[113.706993,-23.560215],[113.843418,-23.059987],[113.736552,-22.475475],[114.149756,-21.755881],[114.225307,-22.517488],[114.647762,-21.82952],[115.460167,-21.495173],[115.947373,-21.068688],[116.711615,-20.701682],[117.166316,-20.623599],[117.441545,-20.746899],[118.229559,-20.374208],[118.836085,-20.263311],[118.987807,-20.044203],[119.252494,-19.952942],[119.805225,-19.976506],[120.85622,-19.683708],[121.399856,-19.239756],[121.655138,-18.705318],[122.241665,-18.197649],[122.286624,-17.798603],[122.312772,-17.254967],[123.012574,-16.4052],[123.433789,-17.268558],[123.859345,-17.069035],[123.503242,-16.596506],[123.817073,-16.111316],[124.258287,-16.327944],[124.379726,-15.56706],[124.926153,-15.0751],[125.167275,-14.680396],[125.670087,-14.51007],[125.685796,-14.230656],[126.125149,-14.347341],[126.142823,-14.095987],[126.582589,-13.952791],[127.065867,-13.817968],[127.804633,-14.276906],[128.35969,-14.86917],[128.985543,-14.875991],[129.621473,-14.969784],[129.4096,-14.42067],[129.888641,-13.618703],[130.339466,-13.357376],[130.183506,-13.10752],[130.617795,-12.536392],[131.223495,-12.183649],[131.735091,-12.302453],[132.575298,-12.114041],[132.557212,-11.603012],[131.824698,-11.273782],[132.357224,-11.128519],[133.019561,-11.376411],[133.550846,-11.786515],[134.393068,-12.042365],[134.678632,-11.941183],[135.298491,-12.248606],[135.882693,-11.962267],[136.258381,-12.049342],[136.492475,-11.857209],[136.95162,-12.351959],[136.685125,-12.887223],[136.305407,-13.29123],[135.961758,-13.324509],[136.077617,-13.724278],[135.783836,-14.223989],[135.428664,-14.715432],[135.500184,-14.997741],[136.295175,-15.550265],[137.06536,-15.870762],[137.580471,-16.215082],[138.303217,-16.807604],[138.585164,-16.806622],[139.108543,-17.062679],[139.260575,-17.371601],[140.215245,-17.710805],[140.875463,-17.369069],[141.07111,-16.832047],[141.274095,-16.38887],[141.398222,-15.840532],[141.702183,-15.044921],[141.56338,-14.561333],[141.63552,-14.270395],[141.519869,-13.698078],[141.65092,-12.944688],[141.842691,-12.741548],[141.68699,-12.407614],[141.928629,-11.877466],[142.118488,-11.328042],[142.143706,-11.042737],[142.51526,-10.668186],[142.79731,-11.157355],[142.866763,-11.784707],[143.115947,-11.90563],[143.158632,-12.325656],[143.522124,-12.834358],[143.597158,-13.400422],[143.561811,-13.763656]]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"CHN","properties":{"name":"China"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[110.339188,18.678395],[109.47521,18.197701],[108.655208,18.507682],[108.626217,19.367888],[109.119056,19.821039],[110.211599,20.101254],[110.786551,20.077534],[111.010051,19.69593],[110.570647,19.255879],[110.339188,18.678395]]],[[[127.657407,49.76027],[129.397818,49.4406],[130.582293,48.729687],[130.987282,47.790132],[132.506672,47.78897],[133.373596,48.183442],[135.026311,48.47823],[134.500814,47.57844],[134.112362,47.212467],[133.769644,46.116927],[133.097127,45.144066],[131.883454,45.321162],[131.025212,44.967953],[131.288555,44.11152],[131.144688,42.92999],[130.633866,42.903015],[130.640016,42.395009],[129.994267,42.985387],[129.596669,42.424982],[128.052215,41.994285],[128.208433,41.466772],[127.343783,41.503152],[126.869083,41.816569],[126.182045,41.107336],[125.079942,40.569824],[124.265625,39.928493],[122.86757,39.637788],[122.131388,39.170452],[121.054554,38.897471],[121.585995,39.360854],[121.376757,39.750261],[122.168595,40.422443],[121.640359,40.94639],[120.768629,40.593388],[119.639602,39.898056],[119.023464,39.252333],[118.042749,39.204274],[117.532702,38.737636],[118.059699,38.061476],[118.87815,37.897325],[118.911636,37.448464],[119.702802,37.156389],[120.823457,37.870428],[121.711259,37.481123],[122.357937,37.454484],[122.519995,36.930614],[121.104164,36.651329],[120.637009,36.11144],[119.664562,35.609791],[119.151208,34.909859],[120.227525,34.360332],[120.620369,33.376723],[121.229014,32.460319],[121.908146,31.692174],[121.891919,30.949352],[121.264257,30.676267],[121.503519,30.142915],[122.092114,29.83252],[121.938428,29.018022],[121.684439,28.225513],[121.125661,28.135673],[120.395473,27.053207],[119.585497,25.740781],[118.656871,24.547391],[117.281606,23.624501],[115.890735,22.782873],[114.763827,22.668074],[114.152547,22.22376],[113.80678,22.54834],[113.241078,22.051367],[111.843592,21.550494],[110.785466,21.397144],[110.444039,20.341033],[109.889861,20.282457],[109.627655,21.008227],[109.864488,21.395051],[108.522813,21.715212],[108.05018,21.55238],[107.04342,21.811899],[106.567273,22.218205],[106.725403,22.794268],[105.811247,22.976892],[105.329209,23.352063],[104.476858,22.81915],[103.504515,22.703757],[102.706992,22.708795],[102.170436,22.464753],[101.652018,22.318199],[101.80312,21.174367],[101.270026,21.201652],[101.180005,21.436573],[101.150033,21.849984],[100.416538,21.558839],[99.983489,21.742937],[99.240899,22.118314],[99.531992,22.949039],[98.898749,23.142722],[98.660262,24.063286],[97.60472,23.897405],[97.724609,25.083637],[98.671838,25.918703],[98.712094,26.743536],[98.68269,27.508812],[98.246231,27.747221],[97.911988,28.335945],[97.327114,28.261583],[96.248833,28.411031],[96.586591,28.83098],[96.117679,29.452802],[95.404802,29.031717],[94.56599,29.277438],[93.413348,28.640629],[92.503119,27.896876],[91.696657,27.771742],[91.258854,28.040614],[90.730514,28.064954],[90.015829,28.296439],[89.47581,28.042759],[88.814248,27.299316],[88.730326,28.086865],[88.120441,27.876542],[86.954517,27.974262],[85.82332,28.203576],[85.011638,28.642774],[84.23458,28.839894],[83.898993,29.320226],[83.337115,29.463732],[82.327513,30.115268],[81.525804,30.422717],[81.111256,30.183481],[79.721367,30.882715],[78.738894,31.515906],[78.458446,32.618164],[79.176129,32.48378],[79.208892,32.994395],[78.811086,33.506198],[78.912269,34.321936],[77.837451,35.49401],[76.192848,35.898403],[75.896897,36.666806],[75.158028,37.133031],[74.980002,37.41999],[74.829986,37.990007],[74.864816,38.378846],[74.257514,38.606507],[73.928852,38.505815],[73.675379,39.431237],[73.960013,39.660008],[73.822244,39.893973],[74.776862,40.366425],[75.467828,40.562072],[76.526368,40.427946],[76.904484,41.066486],[78.187197,41.185316],[78.543661,41.582243],[80.11943,42.123941],[80.25999,42.349999],[80.18015,42.920068],[80.866206,43.180362],[79.966106,44.917517],[81.947071,45.317027],[82.458926,45.53965],[83.180484,47.330031],[85.16429,47.000956],[85.720484,47.452969],[85.768233,48.455751],[86.598776,48.549182],[87.35997,49.214981],[87.751264,49.297198],[88.013832,48.599463],[88.854298,48.069082],[90.280826,47.693549],[90.970809,46.888146],[90.585768,45.719716],[90.94554,45.286073],[92.133891,45.115076],[93.480734,44.975472],[94.688929,44.352332],[95.306875,44.241331],[95.762455,43.319449],[96.349396,42.725635],[97.451757,42.74889],[99.515817,42.524691],[100.845866,42.663804],[101.83304,42.514873],[103.312278,41.907468],[104.522282,41.908347],[104.964994,41.59741],[106.129316,42.134328],[107.744773,42.481516],[109.243596,42.519446],[110.412103,42.871234],[111.129682,43.406834],[111.829588,43.743118],[111.667737,44.073176],[111.348377,44.457442],[111.873306,45.102079],[112.436062,45.011646],[113.463907,44.808893],[114.460332,45.339817],[115.985096,45.727235],[116.717868,46.388202],[117.421701,46.672733],[118.874326,46.805412],[119.66327,46.69268],[119.772824,47.048059],[118.866574,47.74706],[118.064143,48.06673],[117.295507,47.697709],[116.308953,47.85341],[115.742837,47.726545],[115.485282,48.135383],[116.191802,49.134598],[116.678801,49.888531],[117.879244,49.510983],[119.288461,50.142883],[119.279366,50.582908],[120.18205,51.643566],[120.738191,51.964115],[120.725789,52.516226],[120.177089,52.753886],[121.003085,53.251401],[122.245748,53.431726],[123.571507,53.458804],[125.068211,53.161045],[125.946349,52.792799],[126.564399,51.784255],[126.939157,51.353894],[127.287456,50.739797],[127.657407,49.76027]]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"USA","properties":{"name":"United States of America"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-155.54211,19.08348],[-155.68817,18.91619],[-155.93665,19.05939],[-155.90806,19.33888],[-156.07347,19.70294],[-156.02368,19.81422],[-155.85008,19.97729],[-155.91907,20.17395],[-155.86108,20.26721],[-155.78505,20.2487],[-155.40214,20.07975],[-155.22452,19.99302],[-155.06226,19.8591],[-154.80741,19.50871],[-154.83147,19.45328],[-155.22217,19.23972],[-155.54211,19.08348]]],[[[-156.07926,20.64397],[-156.41445,20.57241],[-156.58673,20.783],[-156.70167,20.8643],[-156.71055,20.92676],[-156.61258,21.01249],[-156.25711,20.91745],[-155.99566,20.76404],[-156.07926,20.64397]]],[[[-156.75824,21.17684],[-156.78933,21.06873],[-157.32521,21.09777],[-157.25027,21.21958],[-156.75824,21.17684]]],[[[-157.65283,21.32217],[-157.70703,21.26442],[-157.7786,21.27729],[-158.12667,21.31244],[-158.2538,21.53919],[-158.29265,21.57912],[-158.0252,21.71696],[-157.94161,21.65272],[-157.65283,21.32217]]],[[[-159.34512,21.982],[-159.46372,21.88299],[-159.80051,22.06533],[-159.74877,22.1382],[-159.5962,22.23618],[-159.36569,22.21494],[-159.34512,21.982]]],[[[-94.81758,49.38905],[-94.64,48.84],[-94.32914,48.67074],[-93.63087,48.60926],[-92.61,48.45],[-91.64,48.14],[-90.83,48.27],[-89.6,48.01],[-89.272917,48.019808],[-88.378114,48.302918],[-87.439793,47.94],[-86.461991,47.553338],[-85.652363,47.220219],[-84.87608,46.900083],[-84.779238,46.637102],[-84.543749,46.538684],[-84.6049,46.4396],[-84.3367,46.40877],[-84.14212,46.512226],[-84.091851,46.275419],[-83.890765,46.116927],[-83.616131,46.116927],[-83.469551,45.994686],[-83.592851,45.816894],[-82.550925,45.347517],[-82.337763,44.44],[-82.137642,43.571088],[-82.43,42.98],[-82.9,42.43],[-83.12,42.08],[-83.142,41.975681],[-83.02981,41.832796],[-82.690089,41.675105],[-82.439278,41.675105],[-81.277747,42.209026],[-80.247448,42.3662],[-78.939362,42.863611],[-78.92,42.965],[-79.01,43.27],[-79.171674,43.466339],[-78.72028,43.625089],[-77.737885,43.629056],[-76.820034,43.628784],[-76.5,44.018459],[-76.375,44.09631],[-75.31821,44.81645],[-74.867,45.00048],[-73.34783,45.00738],[-71.50506,45.0082],[-71.405,45.255],[-71.08482,45.30524],[-70.66,45.46],[-70.305,45.915],[-69.99997,46.69307],[-69.237216,47.447781],[-68.905,47.185],[-68.23444,47.35486],[-67.79046,47.06636],[-67.79134,45.70281],[-67.13741,45.13753],[-66.96466,44.8097],[-68.03252,44.3252],[-69.06,43.98],[-70.11617,43.68405],[-70.645476,43.090238],[-70.81489,42.8653],[-70.825,42.335],[-70.495,41.805],[-70.08,41.78],[-70.185,42.145],[-69.88497,41.92283],[-69.96503,41.63717],[-70.64,41.475],[-71.12039,41.49445],[-71.86,41.32],[-72.295,41.27],[-72.87643,41.22065],[-73.71,40.931102],[-72.24126,41.11948],[-71.945,40.93],[-73.345,40.63],[-73.982,40.628],[-73.952325,40.75075],[-74.25671,40.47351],[-73.96244,40.42763],[-74.17838,39.70926],[-74.90604,38.93954],[-74.98041,39.1964],[-75.20002,39.24845],[-75.52805,39.4985],[-75.32,38.96],[-75.071835,38.782032],[-75.05673,38.40412],[-75.37747,38.01551],[-75.94023,37.21689],[-76.03127,37.2566],[-75.72205,37.93705],[-76.23287,38.319215],[-76.35,39.15],[-76.542725,38.717615],[-76.32933,38.08326],[-76.989998,38.239992],[-76.30162,37.917945],[-76.25874,36.9664],[-75.9718,36.89726],[-75.86804,36.55125],[-75.72749,35.55074],[-76.36318,34.80854],[-77.397635,34.51201],[-78.05496,33.92547],[-78.55435,33.86133],[-79.06067,33.49395],[-79.20357,33.15839],[-80.301325,32.509355],[-80.86498,32.0333],[-81.33629,31.44049],[-81.49042,30.72999],[-81.31371,30.03552],[-80.98,29.18],[-80.535585,28.47213],[-80.53,28.04],[-80.056539,26.88],[-80.088015,26.205765],[-80.13156,25.816775],[-80.38103,25.20616],[-80.68,25.08],[-81.17213,25.20126],[-81.33,25.64],[-81.71,25.87],[-82.24,26.73],[-82.70515,27.49504],[-82.85526,27.88624],[-82.65,28.55],[-82.93,29.1],[-83.70959,29.93656],[-84.1,30.09],[-85.10882,29.63615],[-85.28784,29.68612],[-85.7731,30.15261],[-86.4,30.4],[-87.53036,30.27433],[-88.41782,30.3849],[-89.18049,30.31598],[-89.593831,30.159994],[-89.413735,29.89419],[-89.43,29.48864],[-89.21767,29.29108],[-89.40823,29.15961],[-89.77928,29.30714],[-90.15463,29.11743],[-90.880225,29.148535],[-91.626785,29.677],[-92.49906,29.5523],[-93.22637,29.78375],[-93.84842,29.71363],[-94.69,29.48],[-95.60026,28.73863],[-96.59404,28.30748],[-97.14,27.83],[-97.37,27.38],[-97.38,26.69],[-97.33,26.21],[-97.14,25.87],[-97.53,25.84],[-98.24,26.06],[-99.02,26.37],[-99.3,26.84],[-99.52,27.54],[-100.11,28.11],[-100.45584,28.69612],[-100.9576,29.38071],[-101.6624,29.7793],[-102.48,29.76],[-103.11,28.97],[-103.94,29.27],[-104.45697,29.57196],[-104.70575,30.12173],[-105.03737,30.64402],[-105.63159,31.08383],[-106.1429,31.39995],[-106.50759,31.75452],[-108.24,31.754854],[-108.24194,31.34222],[-109.035,31.34194],[-111.02361,31.33472],[-113.30498,32.03914],[-114.815,32.52528],[-114.72139,32.72083],[-115.99135,32.61239],[-117.12776,32.53534],[-117.295938,33.046225],[-117.944,33.621236],[-118.410602,33.740909],[-118.519895,34.027782],[-119.081,34.078],[-119.438841,34.348477],[-120.36778,34.44711],[-120.62286,34.60855],[-120.74433,35.15686],[-121.71457,36.16153],[-122.54747,37.55176],[-122.51201,37.78339],[-122.95319,38.11371],[-123.7272,38.95166],[-123.86517,39.76699],[-124.39807,40.3132],[-124.17886,41.14202],[-124.2137,41.99964],[-124.53284,42.76599],[-124.14214,43.70838],[-124.020535,44.615895],[-123.89893,45.52341],[-124.079635,46.86475],[-124.39567,47.72017],[-124.68721,48.184433],[-124.566101,48.379715],[-123.12,48.04],[-122.58736,47.096],[-122.34,47.36],[-122.5,48.18],[-122.84,49],[-120,49],[-117.03121,49],[-116.04818,49],[-113,49],[-110.05,49],[-107.05,49],[-104.04826,48.99986],[-100.65,49],[-97.22872,49.0007],[-95.15907,49],[-95.15609,49.38425],[-94.81758,49.38905]]],[[[-153.006314,57.115842],[-154.00509,56.734677],[-154.516403,56.992749],[-154.670993,57.461196],[-153.76278,57.816575],[-153.228729,57.968968],[-152.564791,57.901427],[-152.141147,57.591059],[-153.006314,57.115842]]],[[[-165.579164,59.909987],[-166.19277,59.754441],[-166.848337,59.941406],[-167.455277,60.213069],[-166.467792,60.38417],[-165.67443,60.293607],[-165.579164,59.909987]]],[[[-171.731657,63.782515],[-171.114434,63.592191],[-170.491112,63.694975],[-169.682505,63.431116],[-168.689439,63.297506],[-168.771941,63.188598],[-169.52944,62.976931],[-170.290556,63.194438],[-170.671386,63.375822],[-171.553063,63.317789],[-171.791111,63.405846],[-171.731657,63.782515]]],[[[-155.06779,71.147776],[-154.344165,70.696409],[-153.900006,70.889989],[-152.210006,70.829992],[-152.270002,70.600006],[-150.739992,70.430017],[-149.720003,70.53001],[-147.613362,70.214035],[-145.68999,70.12001],[-144.920011,69.989992],[-143.589446,70.152514],[-142.07251,69.851938],[-140.985988,69.711998],[-140.992499,66.000029],[-140.99777,60.306397],[-140.012998,60.276838],[-139.039,60.000007],[-138.34089,59.56211],[-137.4525,58.905],[-136.47972,59.46389],[-135.47583,59.78778],[-134.945,59.27056],[-134.27111,58.86111],[-133.355549,58.410285],[-132.73042,57.69289],[-131.70781,56.55212],[-130.00778,55.91583],[-129.979994,55.284998],[-130.53611,54.802753],[-131.085818,55.178906],[-131.967211,55.497776],[-132.250011,56.369996],[-133.539181,57.178887],[-134.078063,58.123068],[-135.038211,58.187715],[-136.628062,58.212209],[-137.800006,58.499995],[-139.867787,59.537762],[-140.825274,59.727517],[-142.574444,60.084447],[-143.958881,59.99918],[-145.925557,60.45861],[-147.114374,60.884656],[-148.224306,60.672989],[-148.018066,59.978329],[-148.570823,59.914173],[-149.727858,59.705658],[-150.608243,59.368211],[-151.716393,59.155821],[-151.859433,59.744984],[-151.409719,60.725803],[-150.346941,61.033588],[-150.621111,61.284425],[-151.895839,60.727198],[-152.57833,60.061657],[-154.019172,59.350279],[-153.287511,58.864728],[-154.232492,58.146374],[-155.307491,57.727795],[-156.308335,57.422774],[-156.556097,56.979985],[-158.117217,56.463608],[-158.433321,55.994154],[-159.603327,55.566686],[-160.28972,55.643581],[-161.223048,55.364735],[-162.237766,55.024187],[-163.069447,54.689737],[-164.785569,54.404173],[-164.942226,54.572225],[-163.84834,55.039431],[-162.870001,55.348043],[-161.804175,55.894986],[-160.563605,56.008055],[-160.07056,56.418055],[-158.684443,57.016675],[-158.461097,57.216921],[-157.72277,57.570001],[-157.550274,58.328326],[-157.041675,58.918885],[-158.194731,58.615802],[-158.517218,58.787781],[-159.058606,58.424186],[-159.711667,58.93139],[-159.981289,58.572549],[-160.355271,59.071123],[-161.355003,58.670838],[-161.968894,58.671665],[-162.054987,59.266925],[-161.874171,59.633621],[-162.518059,59.989724],[-163.818341,59.798056],[-164.662218,60.267484],[-165.346388,60.507496],[-165.350832,61.073895],[-166.121379,61.500019],[-165.734452,62.074997],[-164.919179,62.633076],[-164.562508,63.146378],[-163.753332,63.219449],[-163.067224,63.059459],[-162.260555,63.541936],[-161.53445,63.455817],[-160.772507,63.766108],[-160.958335,64.222799],[-161.518068,64.402788],[-160.777778,64.788604],[-161.391926,64.777235],[-162.45305,64.559445],[-162.757786,64.338605],[-163.546394,64.55916],[-164.96083,64.446945],[-166.425288,64.686672],[-166.845004,65.088896],[-168.11056,65.669997],[-166.705271,66.088318],[-164.47471,66.57666],[-163.652512,66.57666],[-163.788602,66.077207],[-161.677774,66.11612],[-162.489715,66.735565],[-163.719717,67.116395],[-164.430991,67.616338],[-165.390287,68.042772],[-166.764441,68.358877],[-166.204707,68.883031],[-164.430811,68.915535],[-163.168614,69.371115],[-162.930566,69.858062],[-161.908897,70.33333],[-160.934797,70.44769],[-159.039176,70.891642],[-158.119723,70.824721],[-156.580825,71.357764],[-155.06779,71.147776]]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"ZWE","properties":{"name":"Zimbabwe"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[31.191409,-22.25151],[30.659865,-22.151567],[30.322883,-22.271612],[29.839037,-22.102216],[29.432188,-22.091313],[28.794656,-21.639454],[28.02137,-21.485975],[27.727228,-20.851802],[27.724747,-20.499059],[27.296505,-20.39152],[26.164791,-19.293086],[25.850391,-18.714413],[25.649163,-18.536026],[25.264226,-17.73654],[26.381935,-17.846042],[26.706773,-17.961229],[27.044427,-17.938026],[27.598243,-17.290831],[28.467906,-16.4684],[28.825869,-16.389749],[28.947463,-16.043051],[29.516834,-15.644678],[30.274256,-15.507787],[30.338955,-15.880839],[31.173064,-15.860944],[31.636498,-16.07199],[31.852041,-16.319417],[32.328239,-16.392074],[32.847639,-16.713398],[32.849861,-17.979057],[32.654886,-18.67209],[32.611994,-19.419383],[32.772708,-19.715592],[32.659743,-20.30429],[32.508693,-20.395292],[32.244988,-21.116489],[31.191409,-22.25151]]]}}
]}'
;

select
    id, [name], Geo = fixed 
from   openjson (@worldGeoJson, '$.features')
with
(
    id char(3) '$.id',
    [type] Varchar(64) '$.geometry.type',
    [name] varchar(200) '$.properties.name',
    [coordinates] nvarchar(max) '$.geometry.coordinates' as json
)
as GeoData
OUTER apply (
select 
   stuff( 
      (
        select concat(',  ', json_value(Value,'$[0]'),' ',json_value(Value,'$[1]'))  
        from openjson(GeoData.coordinates,'$[0]') 
        order by cast([key] as int)
        for xml path('')
      ),1,3,'') [path]
    WHERE GeoData.[type] = 'Polygon'
) PolygonData
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  STUFF(
        (
            SELECT CONCAT(',  ', polygon)
            FROM OPENJSON(GeoData.coordinates) as Poly 
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Poly.value) as Shape 
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT '(' + stuff( 
                (
                    select concat(',  ', json_value(Value,'$[0]'),' ',json_value(Value,'$[1]'))  
                    from OPENJSON(Shape.value)
                    order by cast([key] as int)
                    for xml path('')
                ),1,3,'')+')' polygon
        ) Polygons
        for xml path('')
    ),1,3,'') multi
    WHERE GeoData.[type] = 'MultiPolygon'
) MultigonData
cross apply (
    SELECT concat(upper(GeoData.[type]),'((',COALESCE(PolygonData.path, MultigonData.multi),'))') WKT
) shapeDef
outer apply (
select geography::STGeomFromText(WKT,4326).MakeValid()/*.ReorientObject()*/ as geom
) geography
outer apply (
select CASE WHEN geom.EnvelopeAngle() > 90 THEN geom.ReorientObject() ELSE geom END as fixed
) fixes
```

I've used *APPLY* queries here to hopefully make the code a bit easier to understand but also to make it easier for you to inspect the logic and customise it to your needs.

> Notice the *OUTER APPLY* query for `PolygonData` is only returning results `WHERE GeoData.[type] = 'Polygon'` and `MultigonData` is also filtering on the geometry type field. In this way we can avoid query execution errors when the geometry input would not result in valid syntax.
>
> You could continue this pattern for other geometry types if you need them.
>   [Thankyou @Hank and @Vitaly-Borisov for your assistance on this one :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371883/1690217)

MultiPolygon lines were a lot harder to get right, its only 1 additional dimension over a normal polygon but still takes a bit to wrap your head around.

> **MakeValid** is necessary only for some sources, usually the high res stuff but its wise to leave it in there.
>   **ReorientObject** is only necessary for shapes that result in an inverted output, usually this is when the sequence of points is incorrect, so we use the *EnvelopeAngle* to determine if we should re-orient or not. (Reorient on everything can cause some shapes to become inverted.

Comment: Hi Chris, if you're interested I've used your statement, but am having issues, made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371128/issue-on-trying-to-query-geojson-multipolygons-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: Thanks @Hank! I've updated this post with the findings from your question, that's a bit of a rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: This is excellent information @Chris. What would the syntax be for Point-type geometry along with polygon and multi-polygon?

Comment: @SeaDude the above shows polygon and multipolygon, adding point shouldn't be too hard, I have since transitioned my code to C# to cater for the different nuances between GIS providers. However if you post a question with a sample of your JSON that you want parsed (with one of each geometry type) I'll be more than happy to have a crack at it.

Comment: Also @SeaDude see the answer from jovan: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33552784/1690217 it shows specifically how to parse points.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSchaller. Posted a follow up here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011684/how-to-parse-multiple-geojson-feature-types-and-write-to-sql-geography-column.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2016 you can [parse GeoJSON format using OPENJSON function](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/parsing-geojson-format-in-sql-server-2016/ba-p/384459) and then you can convert table of coordinates to spatial types.
Each nested GeoJSON level is handled with one additional CROSS APPLY call. Also, you can [load GeoJSON into spatial columns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2016/01/05/loading-geojson-data-into-sql-server.aspx)
If you don't use SQL Server 2016 or you want to use logic in app layer, then probably the only way is Json.Net.

Comment: These links are broken now, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following replace

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[YourTable]
set  coorGeo = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(coorGeo,'[' , ''), '],', '*'),',',' '),'*',','),']','')
```

Then you can add the geography:

```
update [dbo].[YourTable] set Coordinates = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON(('+coorGeo+'))', 4326);
```