# Issue on trying to query GeoJson multipolygons in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server, gis, geojson, spatial

I am trying to run a query (which I gleened from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371865/convert-geojson-data-to-sql-server-spatial-data-type-gis)) against GeoJson multipolygon data. It processes many of the spatial records but is stopping on a some.

I get the following error in the query messages:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>       A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
>       System.FormatException: 24142: Expected "(" at position 15. The input has ",".
>       System.FormatException:
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeToken(Char token)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseLineStringText()
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePolygonText()
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseMultiPolygonText()
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)

This is my statement with some test data:

```
declare @CountiesGeoJson nvarchar(max) = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "700", "COUNTYNS": "01498555", "GEOID": "51700", "NAME": "Newport News" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-76.622252, 37.142146], [-76.577819, 37.187025], [-76.591432, 37.214721], [-76.565092, 37.220645], [-76.458516, 37.100661], [-76.435519, 37.094882], [-76.451274, 37.076878], [-76.442269, 37.018448], [-76.424757, 37.025107], [-76.387711304409194, 36.989671332859004], [-76.411768, 36.962847], [-76.428869, 36.969947], [-76.464471, 37.027547], [-76.518242, 37.055351], [-76.536875, 37.083942], [-76.564219, 37.077507], [-76.618252, 37.119347], [-76.622252, 37.142146]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "620", "COUNTYNS": "01498424", "GEOID": "51620", "NAME": "Franklin" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-76.963021, 36.704696], [-76.912221, 36.698408], [-76.909672, 36.648175], [-76.962339, 36.667515], [-76.949327, 36.67873], [-76.968027, 36.682971], [-76.963021, 36.704696]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "595", "COUNTYNS": "01498422", "GEOID": "51595", "NAME": "Emporia" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.557359, 36.713166], [-77.510273, 36.718229], [-77.509246, 36.682998], [-77.556524, 36.674874], [-77.557359, 36.713166]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "670", "COUNTYNS": "01498428", "GEOID": "51670", "NAME": "Hopewell" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.334549, 37.312468], [-77.273379, 37.316116], [-77.253234, 37.295668], [-77.31081, 37.261451], [-77.328291, 37.271748], [-77.334549, 37.312468]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "510", "COUNTYNS": "01498415", "GEOID": "51510", "NAME": "Alexandria" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.140872, 38.826905], [-77.110799, 38.843446], [-77.087805, 38.827357], [-77.085609, 38.84419], [-77.044487611898006, 38.839598699716696], [-77.040372554526996, 38.785355394851003], [-77.143135, 38.805321], [-77.140872, 38.826905]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "059", "COUNTYNS": "01480119", "GEOID": "51059", "NAME": "Fairfax" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.53576, 38.847474], [-77.32828109319901, 39.057794871536501], [-77.246003, 39.024909], [-77.255703, 39.002409], [-77.234803, 38.97631], [-77.148179, 38.965002], [-77.119759, 38.934343], [-77.172276, 38.893245], [-77.194712, 38.899073], [-77.194234, 38.886146], [-77.149701, 38.87567], [-77.110799, 38.843446], [-77.140872, 38.826905], [-77.143135, 38.805321], [-77.040372554526996, 38.785355394851003], [-77.042298, 38.718515], [-77.122001, 38.685816], [-77.1302, 38.635017], [-77.204302, 38.617817], [-77.277032, 38.695026], [-77.355884, 38.725425], [-77.370878, 38.710433], [-77.442956, 38.803796], [-77.492801, 38.797821], [-77.50834, 38.841032], [-77.53576, 38.847474]], [[-77.334852, 38.853737], [-77.318689, 38.834651], [-77.27052, 38.840902], [-77.270597, 38.866075], [-77.334852, 38.853737]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "680", "COUNTYNS": "01498429", "GEOID": "51680", "NAME": "Lynchburg" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-79.26745, 37.44744], [-79.183302, 37.465908], [-79.120451, 37.398311], [-79.085244, 37.394743], [-79.214924, 37.33258], [-79.257188, 37.355608], [-79.231933, 37.394911], [-79.256628, 37.406573], [-79.244548, 37.419941], [-79.268727, 37.431028], [-79.26745, 37.44744]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "037", "COUNTYNS": "01492442", "GEOID": "51037", "NAME": "Charlotte" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-78.902227, 37.026799], [-78.824209, 37.205361], [-78.808198, 37.201852], [-78.778353, 37.228639], [-78.734351, 37.220256], [-78.681477, 37.24969], [-78.692432, 37.203673], [-78.644621, 37.194323], [-78.634927, 37.170064], [-78.583642, 37.140635], [-78.547128, 37.150431], [-78.480891, 37.085196], [-78.443644, 37.079371], [-78.493028, 36.89122], [-78.648541, 36.697909], [-78.691328, 36.741847], [-78.666145, 36.764363], [-78.682652, 36.797222], [-78.666995, 36.811822], [-78.686878, 36.824331], [-78.666125, 36.840482], [-78.671463, 36.857951], [-78.749727, 36.920065], [-78.727686, 36.937454], [-78.743891, 37.005439], [-78.756549, 37.00717], [-78.748358, 36.987057], [-78.774715, 36.980976], [-78.785452, 36.952783], [-78.817455, 36.98402], [-78.892702, 36.976694], [-78.902227, 37.026799]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "099", "COUNTYNS": "01480137", "GEOID": "51099", "NAME": "King George" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.330384, 38.334951], [-77.286201505089011, 38.347024428844499], [-77.240072, 38.331598], [-77.17934, 38.341915], [-77.138224, 38.367917], [-77.08481, 38.368297], [-77.043526, 38.400548], [-77.011827, 38.374554], [-77.030683, 38.311623], [-76.99767, 38.278047], [-77.044799, 38.260407], [-77.048482, 38.182444], [-77.073796, 38.141331], [-77.084596, 38.160231], [-77.115997, 38.149931], [-77.2143, 38.197029], [-77.254001, 38.18943], [-77.242001, 38.210729], [-77.251801, 38.229628], [-77.229757, 38.245208], [-77.275302, 38.247528], [-77.291402, 38.223729], [-77.290302, 38.238728], [-77.309419, 38.234737], [-77.345728, 38.26139], [-77.330384, 38.334951]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "161", "COUNTYNS": "01480165", "GEOID": "51161", "NAME": "Roanoke" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-80.261984, 37.340694], [-80.200161, 37.378568], [-80.147625, 37.382342], [-80.073985, 37.422305], [-79.865099, 37.328417], [-79.840367, 37.302681], [-79.858058, 37.267138], [-79.847082, 37.225468], [-79.962301, 37.137099], [-80.030562, 37.17481], [-80.088553, 37.160482], [-80.128119, 37.122912], [-80.172264, 37.108156], [-80.189835, 37.233476], [-80.25852, 37.308344], [-80.261984, 37.340694]], [[-80.088062, 37.282334], [-80.050761, 37.252635], [-80.033464, 37.26289], [-80.02883, 37.24365], [-79.998113, 37.252193], [-79.950384, 37.211274], [-79.924496, 37.224634], [-79.900048, 37.257297], [-79.909493, 37.278054], [-79.879276, 37.304047], [-79.974023, 37.335419], [-80.022226, 37.308338], [-80.033596, 37.324293], [-80.12049, 37.287053], [-80.088062, 37.282334]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "135", "COUNTYNS": "01493928", "GEOID": "51135", "NAME": "Nottoway" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-78.238161, 37.194822], [-78.231234, 37.29622], [-77.795926, 37.192592], [-77.805982, 37.175933], [-77.900254, 37.143885], [-77.889813, 36.988818], [-77.932749, 36.984246], [-77.968114, 36.987292], [-78.003639, 37.022756], [-78.082023, 37.011121], [-78.172207, 37.055963], [-78.170716, 37.076188], [-78.224286, 37.089685], [-78.239354, 37.120089], [-78.238161, 37.194822]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "683", "COUNTYNS": "01498430", "GEOID": "51683", "NAME": "Manassas" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.526457, 38.732466], [-77.475711, 38.781214], [-77.44751, 38.761115], [-77.451642, 38.738337], [-77.471425, 38.728152], [-77.507299, 38.740479], [-77.506167, 38.705741], [-77.526457, 38.732466]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "630", "COUNTYNS": "01498425", "GEOID": "51630", "NAME": "Fredericksburg" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.530283, 38.309175], [-77.506782, 38.325925], [-77.467053, 38.31866], [-77.447126, 38.284614], [-77.457837, 38.271108], [-77.492045, 38.273637], [-77.530283, 38.309175]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "610", "COUNTYNS": "01498423", "GEOID": "51610", "NAME": "Falls Church" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.194712, 38.899073], [-77.172276, 38.893245], [-77.149701, 38.87567], [-77.189719, 38.87801], [-77.194712, 38.899073]]]] } },
]}';
--DECLARE @@CountiesGeoJson nvarchar(max)
--SELECT @@CountiesGeoJson = BulkColumn
--FROM OPENROWSET
--(BULK 'C:\MapData\countiesEdited.json', SINGLE_CLOB)
--as JSON

--Insert Into [Tox].[dbo].[GeoCounties] (GEOID, GEO_NAME, FIPS_ST_CD, FIPS_CNTY_CD, RESOLUTION_ACCURACY, GEO_OBJECT)
select GEOID, GNAME, STATEFP, COUNTYFP, 10, Geo=fixed
from   openjson (@CountiesGeoJson, '$.features')
with
(
    GEOID char(5) '$.properties.GEOID',
    GNAME varchar(40) '$.properties.NAME',
    STATEFP char(2) '$.properties.STATEFP',
    COUNTYFP char(3) '$.properties.COUNTYFP',
    [type] Varchar(64) '$.geometry.type',
    [coordinates] nvarchar(max) '$.geometry.coordinates' as json
)
as GeoData
cross apply (
select 
   stuff( 
      (
        select concat(',  ', json_value(Value,'$[0]'),' ',json_value(Value,'$[1]'))  
        from openjson(GeoData.coordinates,'$[0]') 
        order by cast([key] as int)
        for xml path('')
      ),1,3,'') [path]
) PolygonData
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  STUFF(
        (
            SELECT CONCAT(',  ', polygon)
            FROM OPENJSON(GeoData.coordinates) as Poly 
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Poly.value) as Shape 
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT '(' + stuff( 
                (
                    select concat(',  ', json_value(Value,'$[0]'),' ',json_value(Value,'$[1]'))  
                    from OPENJSON(Shape.value)
                    order by cast([key] as int)
                    for xml path('')
                ),1,3,'')+')' polygon
        ) Polygons
        for xml path('')
    ),1,3,'') multi
    WHERE LEN(Path) = 0
) MultigonData
cross apply (
    SELECT concat(upper(GeoData.[type]),'((',IsNull(NULLIF(path,''),multi),'))') WKT
) shapeDef
outer apply (
    select geography::STGeomFromText(WKT,4326).MakeValid()/*.ReorientObject()*/ as geom
) geography
outer apply (
    select CASE WHEN geom.EnvelopeAngle() > 90 THEN geom.ReorientObject() ELSE geom END as fixed
) fixes
```

The query will run and produce some results but when it hits records where the NAME = 'Fairfax' and 'Roanoke', it stops with the above error.

Can anyone see the issue and know how to resolve this?

[EDIT 2019-05-31 17:35]
GeoJson Header:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "USCounty_Simplify_01",
  "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269" } },
  "features": [
...
```

Comment: Missing END at the "ELSE geom as fixed", but I've replicated the issue. Interesting

Comment: Thank you good spotting, that was my typo, not the reason for above error though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Hank for taking this query for a spin! [@Vitaly-Borisov has highlighted the specific offending geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371883/1690217), this has helped immensely in solving the issue.

In the original Query, there is a `CROSS APPLY` query that creates a result set called `PolygonData`, immediately after that is an `OUTER APLY` that creates a result set called `MultigonData`.

Notice that MultigonData only has results `WHERE LEN(Path) = 0`
The expectation here was that all non polygon geometry would yield a null value for `Path` and so we only attempt to resolve the MultiPolygon WKT if the geometry was indeed a MultiPolygon type.

> This query only supports Polygon and MultiPolygon types of geometry, it was a broad enough assumption that suited at that time.
>
> Instead of using the failure to resolve a Polygon (`WHERE LEN(Path) = 0`) to determine that the geometry is in fact a MultiPolygon, we can use the type definition itself!

Updated Query, notice the where clauses within the `PolygonData` and `MutigonData` queries and the use of `COALESCE` in `shapeDef`
These minor changes should make it easier to adopt this logic for other geography types.

```
declare @CountiesGeoJson nvarchar(max) = '{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "USCounty_Simplify_01", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269" } }, "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "700", "COUNTYNS": "01498555", "GEOID": "51700", "NAME": "Newport News" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-76.622252, 37.142146], [-76.577819, 37.187025], [-76.591432, 37.214721], [-76.565092, 37.220645], [-76.458516, 37.100661], [-76.435519, 37.094882], [-76.451274, 37.076878], [-76.442269, 37.018448], [-76.424757, 37.025107], [-76.387711304409194, 36.989671332859004], [-76.411768, 36.962847], [-76.428869, 36.969947], [-76.464471, 37.027547], [-76.518242, 37.055351], [-76.536875, 37.083942], [-76.564219, 37.077507], [-76.618252, 37.119347], [-76.622252, 37.142146]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "620", "COUNTYNS": "01498424", "GEOID": "51620", "NAME": "Franklin" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-76.963021, 36.704696], [-76.912221, 36.698408], [-76.909672, 36.648175], [-76.962339, 36.667515], [-76.949327, 36.67873], [-76.968027, 36.682971], [-76.963021, 36.704696]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "595", "COUNTYNS": "01498422", "GEOID": "51595", "NAME": "Emporia" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.557359, 36.713166], [-77.510273, 36.718229], [-77.509246, 36.682998], [-77.556524, 36.674874], [-77.557359, 36.713166]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "670", "COUNTYNS": "01498428", "GEOID": "51670", "NAME": "Hopewell" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.334549, 37.312468], [-77.273379, 37.316116], [-77.253234, 37.295668], [-77.31081, 37.261451], [-77.328291, 37.271748], [-77.334549, 37.312468]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "510", "COUNTYNS": "01498415", "GEOID": "51510", "NAME": "Alexandria" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.140872, 38.826905], [-77.110799, 38.843446], [-77.087805, 38.827357], [-77.085609, 38.84419], [-77.044487611898006, 38.839598699716696], [-77.040372554526996, 38.785355394851003], [-77.143135, 38.805321], [-77.140872, 38.826905]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "059", "COUNTYNS": "01480119", "GEOID": "51059", "NAME": "Fairfax" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.53576, 38.847474], [-77.32828109319901, 39.057794871536501], [-77.246003, 39.024909], [-77.255703, 39.002409], [-77.234803, 38.97631], [-77.148179, 38.965002], [-77.119759, 38.934343], [-77.172276, 38.893245], [-77.194712, 38.899073], [-77.194234, 38.886146], [-77.149701, 38.87567], [-77.110799, 38.843446], [-77.140872, 38.826905], [-77.143135, 38.805321], [-77.040372554526996, 38.785355394851003], [-77.042298, 38.718515], [-77.122001, 38.685816], [-77.1302, 38.635017], [-77.204302, 38.617817], [-77.277032, 38.695026], [-77.355884, 38.725425], [-77.370878, 38.710433], [-77.442956, 38.803796], [-77.492801, 38.797821], [-77.50834, 38.841032], [-77.53576, 38.847474]], [[-77.334852, 38.853737], [-77.318689, 38.834651], [-77.27052, 38.840902], [-77.270597, 38.866075], [-77.334852, 38.853737]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "680", "COUNTYNS": "01498429", "GEOID": "51680", "NAME": "Lynchburg" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-79.26745, 37.44744], [-79.183302, 37.465908], [-79.120451, 37.398311], [-79.085244, 37.394743], [-79.214924, 37.33258], [-79.257188, 37.355608], [-79.231933, 37.394911], [-79.256628, 37.406573], [-79.244548, 37.419941], [-79.268727, 37.431028], [-79.26745, 37.44744]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "037", "COUNTYNS": "01492442", "GEOID": "51037", "NAME": "Charlotte" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-78.902227, 37.026799], [-78.824209, 37.205361], [-78.808198, 37.201852], [-78.778353, 37.228639], [-78.734351, 37.220256], [-78.681477, 37.24969], [-78.692432, 37.203673], [-78.644621, 37.194323], [-78.634927, 37.170064], [-78.583642, 37.140635], [-78.547128, 37.150431], [-78.480891, 37.085196], [-78.443644, 37.079371], [-78.493028, 36.89122], [-78.648541, 36.697909], [-78.691328, 36.741847], [-78.666145, 36.764363], [-78.682652, 36.797222], [-78.666995, 36.811822], [-78.686878, 36.824331], [-78.666125, 36.840482], [-78.671463, 36.857951], [-78.749727, 36.920065], [-78.727686, 36.937454], [-78.743891, 37.005439], [-78.756549, 37.00717], [-78.748358, 36.987057], [-78.774715, 36.980976], [-78.785452, 36.952783], [-78.817455, 36.98402], [-78.892702, 36.976694], [-78.902227, 37.026799]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "099", "COUNTYNS": "01480137", "GEOID": "51099", "NAME": "King George" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.330384, 38.334951], [-77.286201505089011, 38.347024428844499], [-77.240072, 38.331598], [-77.17934, 38.341915], [-77.138224, 38.367917], [-77.08481, 38.368297], [-77.043526, 38.400548], [-77.011827, 38.374554], [-77.030683, 38.311623], [-76.99767, 38.278047], [-77.044799, 38.260407], [-77.048482, 38.182444], [-77.073796, 38.141331], [-77.084596, 38.160231], [-77.115997, 38.149931], [-77.2143, 38.197029], [-77.254001, 38.18943], [-77.242001, 38.210729], [-77.251801, 38.229628], [-77.229757, 38.245208], [-77.275302, 38.247528], [-77.291402, 38.223729], [-77.290302, 38.238728], [-77.309419, 38.234737], [-77.345728, 38.26139], [-77.330384, 38.334951]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "161", "COUNTYNS": "01480165", "GEOID": "51161", "NAME": "Roanoke" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-80.261984, 37.340694], [-80.200161, 37.378568], [-80.147625, 37.382342], [-80.073985, 37.422305], [-79.865099, 37.328417], [-79.840367, 37.302681], [-79.858058, 37.267138], [-79.847082, 37.225468], [-79.962301, 37.137099], [-80.030562, 37.17481], [-80.088553, 37.160482], [-80.128119, 37.122912], [-80.172264, 37.108156], [-80.189835, 37.233476], [-80.25852, 37.308344], [-80.261984, 37.340694]], [[-80.088062, 37.282334], [-80.050761, 37.252635], [-80.033464, 37.26289], [-80.02883, 37.24365], [-79.998113, 37.252193], [-79.950384, 37.211274], [-79.924496, 37.224634], [-79.900048, 37.257297], [-79.909493, 37.278054], [-79.879276, 37.304047], [-79.974023, 37.335419], [-80.022226, 37.308338], [-80.033596, 37.324293], [-80.12049, 37.287053], [-80.088062, 37.282334]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "135", "COUNTYNS": "01493928", "GEOID": "51135", "NAME": "Nottoway" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-78.238161, 37.194822], [-78.231234, 37.29622], [-77.795926, 37.192592], [-77.805982, 37.175933], [-77.900254, 37.143885], [-77.889813, 36.988818], [-77.932749, 36.984246], [-77.968114, 36.987292], [-78.003639, 37.022756], [-78.082023, 37.011121], [-78.172207, 37.055963], [-78.170716, 37.076188], [-78.224286, 37.089685], [-78.239354, 37.120089], [-78.238161, 37.194822]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "683", "COUNTYNS": "01498430", "GEOID": "51683", "NAME": "Manassas" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.526457, 38.732466], [-77.475711, 38.781214], [-77.44751, 38.761115], [-77.451642, 38.738337], [-77.471425, 38.728152], [-77.507299, 38.740479], [-77.506167, 38.705741], [-77.526457, 38.732466]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "630", "COUNTYNS": "01498425", "GEOID": "51630", "NAME": "Fredericksburg" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.530283, 38.309175], [-77.506782, 38.325925], [-77.467053, 38.31866], [-77.447126, 38.284614], [-77.457837, 38.271108], [-77.492045, 38.273637], [-77.530283, 38.309175]]]] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "610", "COUNTYNS": "01498423", "GEOID": "51610", "NAME": "Falls Church" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.194712, 38.899073], [-77.172276, 38.893245], [-77.149701, 38.87567], [-77.189719, 38.87801], [-77.194712, 38.899073]]]] } },
]}';
--DECLARE @@CountiesGeoJson nvarchar(max)
--SELECT @@CountiesGeoJson = BulkColumn
--FROM OPENROWSET
--(BULK 'C:\MapData\countiesEdited.json', SINGLE_CLOB)
--as JSON

--Insert Into [Tox].[dbo].[GeoCounties] (GEOID, GEO_NAME, FIPS_ST_CD, FIPS_CNTY_CD, RESOLUTION_ACCURACY, GEO_OBJECT)
select GEOID, GNAME, STATEFP, COUNTYFP, 10, Geo=fixed
from   openjson (@CountiesGeoJson, '$.features')
with
(
    GEOID char(5) '$.properties.GEOID',
    GNAME varchar(40) '$.properties.NAME',
    STATEFP char(2) '$.properties.STATEFP',
    COUNTYFP char(3) '$.properties.COUNTYFP',
    [type] Varchar(64) '$.geometry.type',
    [coordinates] nvarchar(max) '$.geometry.coordinates' as json
)
as GeoData
OUTER APPLY (
select 
   stuff( 
      (
        select concat(',  ', json_value(Value,'$[0]'),' ',json_value(Value,'$[1]'))  
        from openjson(GeoData.coordinates,'$[0]') 
        order by cast([key] as int)
        for xml path('')
      ),1,3,'') [path]
      WHERE GeoData.[type] = 'Polygon'
) PolygonData
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  STUFF(
        (
            SELECT CONCAT(',  ', polygon)
            FROM OPENJSON(GeoData.coordinates) as Poly 
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Poly.value) as Shape 
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT '(' + stuff( 
                (
                    select concat(',  ', json_value(Value,'$[0]'),' ',json_value(Value,'$[1]'))  
                    from OPENJSON(Shape.value)
                    order by cast([key] as int)
                    for xml path('')
                ),1,3,'')+')' polygon
        ) Polygons
        for xml path('')
    ),1,3,'') multi
    WHERE GeoData.[type] = 'MultiPolygon'
) MultigonData
cross apply (
    SELECT concat(upper(GeoData.[type]),'((',COALESCE(PolygonData.path, MultigonData.multi),'))') WKT
) shapeDef
-- Extract the SRID from the feature collection header.
outer apply (
    select ID = Substring(name, CharIndex('::', name) + 2, LEN(name) - CharIndex('::', name)) from  openjson (@CountiesGeoJson, '$.crs.properties')
    with ( name varchar(100) '$.name')
) SRID
outer apply (
    select geography::STGeomFromText(WKT,IsNull(SRID.ID, 4326)).MakeValid()/*.ReorientObject()*/ as geom
) geography
outer apply (
    select CASE WHEN geom.EnvelopeAngle() > 90 THEN geom.ReorientObject() ELSE geom END as fixed
) fixes
```

> UPDATE: The feature collection header has been modified to match OP.
>   SRID now comes from the feature collection header and is not hard coded

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you, if I hadn't come across this it would be off to ogr2ogr and I would have been none the wiser. I had one more followup question in most GeoJson file you have a header, I have added my header to the question above. It has a different projection SRID number than 4326, correct me if I'm wrong of course, should I and if so how can I should this into the statement?

Comment: The simplest way is to just change the hardcoded SRID in the script, so you could use this line instead `select geography::STGeomFromText(WKT,4269).MakeValid()` Unless you were going to turn this into a function or you had many different types of GeoJson to process I wouldn't try to make it any more complicated than that. Shouldn't be too hard though, I'll give it a crack

Comment: @Hank I've updated my answer to include parsing and using the SRID from the feature collection header information.

Comment: That's great, thanks Chris, Vitaly and Michael, certainly a collaborative effort

Answer (score 1):

I've reduced testing data to:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "51", "COUNTYFP": "059", "COUNTYNS": "01480119", "GEOID": "51059", "NAME": "Fairfax" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-77.53576, 38.847474], [-77.32828109319901, 39.057794871536501], [-77.246003, 39.024909], [-77.255703, 39.002409], [-77.234803, 38.97631], [-77.148179, 38.965002], [-77.119759, 38.934343], [-77.172276, 38.893245], [-77.194712, 38.899073], [-77.194234, 38.886146], [-77.149701, 38.87567], [-77.110799, 38.843446], [-77.140872, 38.826905], [-77.143135, 38.805321], [-77.040372554526996, 38.785355394851003], [-77.042298, 38.718515], [-77.122001, 38.685816], [-77.1302, 38.635017], [-77.204302, 38.617817], [-77.277032, 38.695026], [-77.355884, 38.725425], [-77.370878, 38.710433], [-77.442956, 38.803796], [-77.492801, 38.797821], [-77.50834, 38.841032], [-77.53576, 38.847474]], [[-77.334852, 38.853737], [-77.318689, 38.834651], [-77.27052, 38.840902], [-77.270597, 38.866075], [-77.334852, 38.853737]]]] } }
  ]}
```

I've commented out last outer apply and select WKT to see what's in.

```
SELECT GEOID, GNAME, STATEFP, COUNTYFP, 10--, Geo=fixed
    ,WKT
```

WKT returns:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(( ,   ))
```

So "geography::STGeomFromText(WKT,4326).MakeValid()" cannot build geometry out of this data and fails with the error.

Comment: Thanks for isolating that as the offending row. Basically complex algorithms like this are built up as we deal with each exception, you have however identified the fundamental flaw, instead of trying to test if the WKT is a polygon or a multi, we should actually use the geometry type as the discriminator!

Answer (score 1):

The failing multipolygons are those that contain holes. You can detect them by searching for `]],`.

Multipolygon is collection of polygons. Each of them is collection of loops - first loop is polygon shell and other loops are holes. Each loop is collection of points.

The script tries to convert GeoJSON to WKT by unpacking these arrays, then concatenating them wrapping using WKT's `(` and `)`, but fails to handle polygon with holes case. I suspect the bug is in `Poly.value` - this does not handle array case, but I'm not OPENJSON expert.

I guess it is possible to continue making this complicated SQL even more complex, and handle holes case as well, but I think it is more practical to convert GeoJSON to WKT strings using something with real GeoJSON parser and WKT formatter, e.g. ogr2ogr tool.